# Rollup bundling peer dependencies / Multiple instances of MUI make the ThemeProvider not work

Tags: npm, material-ui, next.js, rollup, lerna

I have two different repos I'm working on, `lib` and `apps`.

- `lib` has some React components made with [MUI](https://mui.com/) that I want to consume in `apps`, and that's built with Rollup.
- `apps` is a Lerna monorepo with a Next.js app that imports `lib` as a dependency to consume its components, which can be customized wrapping them in a [`<ThemeProvider>`](https://mui.com/customization/theming/#theme-provider) with a custom theme.

However, that doesn't work because there are duplicated instances of MUI / `ThemeProvider`, which I was able to verify by adding this to `lib`'s entry point:

```
if (process.browser) {
  (window as any)._React = React;
  (window as any)._ThemeProvider = ThemeProvider;
}
```

And then this into `apps`':

```
if (process.browser) {
  const {
    _React,
    _ThemeProvider,
  } = window as any;

  console.log(_React ? (_React === React ? "✅ Unique React" : "❌ Duplicate React") : "-");
  console.log(_ThemeProvider ? (_ThemeProvider === ThemeProvider ? "✅ Unique ThemeProvider" : "❌ Duplicate ThemeProvider") : "-");
}
```

Which prints:

```
✅ Unique React
❌ Duplicate ThemeProvider
```

`lib`'s component usage in `app` looks like this:

```
<ThemeProvider theme={ MY_CUSTOM_THEME }>
  <MyComponent{ ...myComponentProps } />
</ThemeProvider>
```

Where both `MyComponent` and `MY_CUSTOM_THEME` are imported from `lib`, while `ThemeProvider` is imported from `@mui/material/styles`, just like it is in `lib`.

However, all MUI components will be displayed with the default theme.

Here are some of the relevant build files for both repos:

`lib > package.json`:

```
{
  "name": "@myscope/lib",
  "version": "1.0.0-alpha",
  "description": "",
  "main": "dist/cjs/src/index.js",
  "module": "dist/esm/src/index.js",
  "types": "dist/index.d.ts",
  "files": [
    "dist"
  ],
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "build": "rollup -c",
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@apollo/client": "^3.4.5",
    "@apollo/link-context": "^2.0.0-beta.3",
    "@hookform/resolvers": "^2.8.5",
    "@mui/icons-material": "^5.0.4",
    "@swyg/corre": "^1.0.1",
    "apollo-upload-client": "^16.0.0",
    "atob": "^2.1.2",
    "axios": "^0.24.0",
    "btoa": "^1.2.1",
    "country-codes-list": "^1.6.8",
    "country-region-data": "^1.6.0",
    "next": "^11.0.1",
    "next-images": "^1.8.2",
    "openpgp": "^5.0.0",
    "react-hook-form": "^7.22.0",
    "react-payment-inputs": "^1.1.8",
    "react-use-country-region": "^1.0.0",
    "styled-components": "^5.3.0",
    "use-callback-ref": "^1.2.5",
    "uuidv4": "^6.2.12",
    "yup": "^0.32.11"
  },
  "peerDependencies": {
    "@mui/material": "^5.0.4",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react": "^17.0.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@auth0/auth0-react": "^1.6.0",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.16.7",
    "@emotion/react": "^11.5.0",
    "@emotion/styled": "^11.3.0",
    "@graphql-codegen/cli": "^1.21.5",
    "@graphql-codegen/introspection": "^1.18.2",
    "@graphql-codegen/typescript-operations": "^1.18.0",
    "@graphql-codegen/typescript-react-apollo": "^2.2.5",
    "@graphql-codegen/typescript": "^1.22.1",
    "@mui/material": "^5.2.8",
    "@rollup/plugin-babel": "^5.3.0",
    "@rollup/plugin-commonjs": "^21.0.1",
    "@rollup/plugin-node-resolve": "^13.1.2",
    "@rollup/plugin-typescript": "^8.3.0",
    "@testing-library/dom": "^8.1.0",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.14.1",
    "@testing-library/react": "^12.0.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.2.1",
    "@types/jest": "^26.0.24",
    "@types/react-dom": "^17.0.11",
    "@types/react": "^17.0.16",
    "@types/styled-components": "^5.1.12",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^4.29.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^4.29.0",
    "babel-jest": "^27.0.6",
    "babel-plugin-styled-components": "^2.0.2",
    "eslint-config-next": "^11.0.1",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^8.3.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^4.2.0",
    "eslint-plugin-unused-imports": "^1.1.2",
    "eslint": "^7.32.0",
    "graphql": "^16.2.0",
    "jest": "^27.0.6",
    "prettier": "^2.3.2",
    "rollup-plugin-dts": "^4.1.0",
    "rollup-plugin-node-externals": "^3.1.2",
    "rollup-plugin-peer-deps-external": "^2.2.4",
    "rollup-plugin-typescript2": "^0.31.1",
    "rollup": "^2.63.0",
    "ts-jest": "^27.0.4",
    "typescript": "^4.3.5"
  }
}
```

Note that `@mui/material` appears both in `peerDependencies` and `devDependencies`, but not `react` or `rect-dom`, which are only listed as `peerDependencies`. That's because there's `@types/react` and `@types/react-dom`, but nothing similar for MUI, so the Rollup build would fail if it can't find the right types.

`lib > rollup.config.js`:

```
import commonjs from '@rollup/plugin-commonjs';
import dts from 'rollup-plugin-dts'
import resolve from "@rollup/plugin-node-resolve";
import typescript from 'rollup-plugin-typescript2'
import babel from '@rollup/plugin-babel'

import pkg from "./package.json";

// Extensions handled by babel:
const EXTENSIONS = [".ts", ".tsx"];

// Exclude dev and peer dependencies:
const EXTERNAL = [
  ...Object.keys(pkg.devDependencies),
  ...Object.keys(pkg.peerDependencies),
];

export default [{
    input: 'src/index.ts',

    output: [{
        dir: "dist/esm",
        sourcemap: true,
        format: "esm",
        preserveModules: true,
        globals: {
          react: "React",
        },
    }, {
        dir: "dist/cjs",
        sourcemap: true,
        format: "cjs",
        preserveModules: true,
        globals: {
          react: "React",
        },
    }],

    external: EXTERNAL,
    
    plugins: [
       resolve(),

        commonjs({
            exclude: "node_modules",
            ignoreGlobal: true,
        }),

        typescript({
          useTsconfigDeclarationDir: true,
          tsconfig: "rollup.tsconfig.json",
        }),
    ],

}, {
    input: './dist/types/src/index.d.ts',
    output: [{ file: './dist/index.d.ts', format: "esm" }],
    external: EXTERNAL,
    plugins: [dts()],
}];
```

`apps > lerna.json`:

```
{
  "packages": ["apps/**/*", "packages/**/*"],
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "npmClient": "yarn",
  "useWorkspaces": true
}
```

`apps > package.json`:

```
...
"dependencies": {
    "@myscope/lib": "file:../lib"
},
...
```

Note this is a `file:` import just to make it easier to develop and test changes.

I've also tried adding `resolutions` to both `apps > package.json` and `apps > app > package.json`, but no luck with that either...:

```
"resolutions": {
  "@mui/material": "5.2.8"
}
```

Comment: Haven't looked at this in depth, but noticed you have installed rollup-plugin-peer-deps-external, but don't appear to be using it in your rollup.config.js

Comment: @RichardWilbur True, that was probably from me trying different options, but in `rollup.config.js` you can see there's `external: EXTERNAL` which should have the same effect.

Comment: I don't think so. If you want to use the plugin, you'll need an import statement:

`import external from 'rollup-plugin-peer-deps-external';`

and use it in the plugins section:

`// eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/no-unsafe-call`
`external(),`

I have mine listed as the first plugin. There may be a reason for that. Also, I haven't found a way around the TypeScript warning, so thats why I disabled it. Hope that helps. Not sure if you're still having an issue or not. Just happened to see your post while trying to find an answer to the TS warning

Comment: Have you made any progress on this issue? :-( I've been stuck for two weeks